# SQL regexp to extract alphanumeric data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have STRING data with no space between alphabet and numeric as follow

```
Fall2022
Spring2014
Winter2014
Summer2012
```

If I want to extract all 2014 data, how should I write the queries?

Expected result

```
Spring2014
Winter2014
```

I have tried regexp and it does not work, I am running this on BigQuery in Google cloud

Comment: You can use a sql like in this case : `column like "%2014%"`

Comment: To split between season name and year, you can use `substring`, if the year is always 4 digit. `select substring(x,1,length(x)-4), substring(x,length(x)-3,4) from unnest(split("Fall2022 Spring2014 Winter2014 Summer2012"," ")) x`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.